# WebView HTML Rendering Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview

I am building an application in react native. I have a use case where I have to open some eSinger gateway (like payment gateway open in the web application). in this gateway, I have to post form with PDF file's base64 data from the background so they can redirect me to their gateway page, but sometimes a string of HTML which I use to render this page is too large and it breaks the web view.

The code in the `render()` of the component is:

```
<WebView
   source={{html: this.state.data}}
   scalesPageToFit={true}
   onNavigationStateChange={ this.onNavigationStateChange.bind(this) }
 />
```

I am initialise **data** in **constructor** with the string like:

```
let data = `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html><head><script type = "text/javascript" src = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script><link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"><title>Verigo</title></head><body style="margin-top:10%;margin-left:10%;margin-right:10%;"><form action="` + POST_URL + `" id="frmdata" method="post"><input id="File" Name="File" type="hidden"/><input id="Name" name="Name" type="hidden" value=""><input id="SelectPage" name="SelectPage" type="hidden" value="ALL"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SignatureType must be a number." data-val-required="The SignatureType field is required." id="SignatureType" name="SignatureType" type="hidden" value="3"><input id="SignaturePosition" name="SignaturePosition" type="hidden" value="Customize"><input id="AuthToken" name="AuthToken" type="hidden" value=""><input id="PageNumber" name="PageNumber" type="hidden" value=""><input id="Data" name="Data" type="hidden" value=""><input id="FileType" name="FileType" type="hidden" value="PDF"><input data-val="true" data-val-required="The PreviewRequired field is required." id="PreviewRequired" name="PreviewRequired" type="hidden" value="True"><input id="CustomizeCoordinates" name="CustomizeCoordinates" type="hidden" value=""><input id="PagelevelCoordinates" name="PagelevelCoordinates" type="hidden" value=""><input id="ReferenceNumber" name="ReferenceNumber" type="hidden" value=""><input id="IsCosign" name="IsCosign" type="hidden" value=""><input id="SUrl" name="SUrl" type="hidden" value=""><input id="CUrl" name="CUrl" type="hidden" value=""><input id="FUrl" name="FUrl" type="hidden" value=""><center style="position:absolute;top:35%;left:5%"><div><img src="/Content/Img/ajax-loader.gif"><div><p style="font-size:15px;">Redirect to Aadhaar OTP screen.Please don't cancel or press back.This process can take some time.</p></div></div></center></form><script type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {$('#ReferenceNumber').val('` + this.props.transaction_id + `');$('#FileType').val('PDF');$('#File').val('` + this.props.base64 + `');$('#Name').val('` + this.props.sign_payload.user_name + `');$('#AuthToken').val('` + this.props.auth_token + `');$('#SignatureType').val('3');$('#SelectPage').val('ALL');$('#SignaturePosition').val('Customize');$('#PageNumber').val('');$('#PagelevelCoordinates').val('');$('#CustomizeCoordinates').val('` + [this.props.sign_payload.yx, this.props.sign_payload.yy, 150, 150].join(",") + `');$('#PreviewRequired').val('False');$('#IsCosign').val('True');$('#SUrl').val('` + surl + `');$('#FUrl').val('` + furl + `');$('#CUrl').val('` + curl + `');$('#frmdata').submit();});</script></body></html>`
```

Main javascript code in above HTML is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {$('#ReferenceNumber').val('` + this.props.transaction_id + `');$('#FileType').val('PDF');$('#File').val('` + this.props.base64 + `');$('#Name').val('` + this.props.sign_payload.user_name + `');$('#AuthToken').val('` + this.props.auth_token + `');$('#SignatureType').val('3');$('#SelectPage').val('ALL');$('#SignaturePosition').val('Customize');$('#PageNumber').val('');$('#PagelevelCoordinates').val('');$('#CustomizeCoordinates').val('` + [this.props.sign_payload.yx, this.props.sign_payload.yy, 150, 150].join(",") + `');$('#PreviewRequired').val('False');$('#IsCosign').val('True');$('#SUrl').val('` + surl + `');$('#FUrl').val('` + furl + `');$('#CUrl').val('` + curl + `');$('#frmdata').submit();});
```

When base64 of the file of size around 1 MB is working but after that is start breaking.
my HTML string length is 4548156.

How much long HTML string i can pass to WebView?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You seem to be setting the value as `$('#File').val('+ this.props.base64+');` Is it really required? Why are you trying to inject so much data into the DOM?

Comment: Yes, I required posting base64 data to eSign POST API for redirecting me to their gateway page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data String that I was using for rendering the DOM is too long(due to base64) so it is not able to render.
I solved it by calling my API which gives me base64 data in above javascript by ajax call and settings base64 to #File at runtime which solves this problem.